# Check if a variable is time invariant in R

Tags: r, variables, time, constants

I tried to search an answer to my question but I find the right answer for Stata (I am using R).

I am using a national survey to study which variables influence the investment in complementary pension (it is voluntary in my country).

The survey is conducted every two years and some individuals are interviewed more than one time. I filtered the df in order to have only the individuals present more than one time trought the `filter` command. This is an example from the original survey already filtered:

```
year  id  y.b   sex   income   pens   
2002  1   1950   F    100000     0     
2002  2   1943   M    55000      1    
2004  1   1950   F    88000      1    
2004  2   1943   M    66000      1    
2006  3   1966   M    12000      1    
2008  3   1966   M    24000      1    
2008  4   1972   F    33000      0    
2010  4   1972   F    35000      0
```

where id is the individual, y.b is year of birth, pens is a dummy which takes value 1 if the individual invests in a complementary pension form.
I wanted to run a FE regression so I load the `plm` package and then I set the df like this:

```
df.p <- plm.data(df, c("id", "year")
```

After this command, I expected that constant variables were deleted but after running this regression:

```
pan1 <- plm (pens ~ woman + age + I(age^2) + high + medium + north + centre, model="within", effect = "individual", data=dd.p, na.action = na.omit)
```

(where woman is a variable which takes value 1 if the individual is a woman, high, medium refer to education level and north, centre to geographical regions) and after the command `summary(pan1)` the variable woman is still present.

At this point I think that there are some mistakes in the survey (for example sex was not insert correctly and so it wasn't the same for the same id), so I tried to find a way to check if for each id, sex is constant.

I tried this code but I am sure it is not correct:

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$id==df$id & df$sex==df$sex,1,0)
```

the basic idea shuold be like this:

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$id=="1" & df$sex=="F",1,0)
```

but I can't do it manually since the df is composed up to 40k observations.

If you know another way to check if a variable is constant in R I will be glad.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Either `df$x <- (ave(df$sex, df$id, FUN = function(x)length(unique(x))) == 1)*1` or `aggregate(sex ~ id, df, FUN = function(i) length(unique(i))==1)*1` depending on how you want your output.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is calculate the number of unique values of `sex` for each `id`. You are hoping it is 1, but any cases of 2 indicate a transcription error. The way to do this in R is

```
any(by(df$sex,df$id,function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1)
```

To break that down, the function `length(unique(x))` tells you the number of different unique values in a vector. It's similar to `levels` for a factor (but not identical, since a factor can have levels not present).

The function `by` calculates the given function on each subset of `df$sex` according to `df$id`. In other words, it calculates `length(unique(df$sex))` where `df$id` is 1, then 2, etc.

Lastly, `any(... > 1)` checks if any of the results are more than one. If they are, the result will be `TRUE` (and you can use `which` instead of `any` to find which ones). If everything is okay, the result will be `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `dplyr`
Example data:

```
df=data.frame(year=c(2002,2002,2004,2004,2006,2008,2008,2010),
              id=c(1,2,1,2,3,3,4,4),
              sex=c("F","M","M","M","M","M","F","F"))
```

Id 1 is both F and M

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%group_by(id)%>%summarise(sexes=length(unique(sex)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     id sexes
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     1
3     3     1
4     4     1
```

We can then filter:

```
df%>%group_by(id)%>%summarise(sexes=length(unique(sex)))%>%filter(sexes==2)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id sexes
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
```